# Plot Bode diagram of all-pass filter

Tags: python, filter, scipy, signals

I am trying to plot the Bode diagram of an all-pass filter. However, the output is different from what it should be. Shouldn't the magnitude be constant?
I am using this formula for all-pass filter:
[image]

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sys = signal.TransferFunction([0.5, 1], [1, 0.5])
print("Zeros {}".format(sys.zeros))
print("Poles {}".format(sys.poles))
w, mag, phase = sys.bode()

plt.figure()
plt.title("Mag")
plt.semilogx(w, mag)    # Bode magnitude plot
plt.figure()
plt.title("Phase")
plt.semilogx(w, phase)  # Bode phase plot
plt.show()
```

Output:
*Zeros [-2.]
Poles [-0.5]*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your definition is for a continuous time system. You need a discrete time system then it would give a constant output.